# Proper algorithm for XQueryTree to get in z order

Tags: algorithm, x11

I was trying to get all the windows in z order but the algorithm for XQueryTree is confusing me. This is what I did:

my collection array: `[]`

1. I start with root window lets call this `A`, I push this to start of array. So `[A]`
2. XQueryTree gives me a list of a children lets call them B, C, D
3. I push first child to start of array so it is now `[B, A]`
4. It XQueryTree `B` and finds children `B1, B2`
5. It pushes B1 to start so now: `[B1, B, A]`
6. XQuertyTree on B1 shows no children so continues
7. It pushes `B2` so now `[B2, B1, B, A]`
8. It XqueryTree B2 and it finds no children, so it continues
9. It pushes `C` to start so now `[C, B2, B1, B, A]`
10. It XQueryTree `C` and finds no children so continue
11. It pushes `D` to start so now `[D, C, B2, B1, B, A]`
12. It XquertyTree `D` and finds no children

I was debating this myself as I was writing the algo, is this the right algorigthm in z order from top most to bottom most? Its not seeming right when I implement it with my code below. `D` should be the top most in z order and `A` the bottom most.

This is my code right now:

```
var rezWinArr = [];
var processWin = function(w) {

    rezWinArr.splice(0, 0, thisWin); // puts the win into the array at position 0

    var rez_XQ = ostypes.API('XQueryTree')(ostypes.HELPER.cachedXOpenDisplay(), w, xqRoot.address(), xqParent.address(), xqChildArr.address(), nChilds.address()); // interesting note about XQueryTree and workspaces: "The problem with this approach is that it will only return windows on the same virtual desktop.  In the case of multiple virtual desktops, windows on other virtual desktops will be ignored." source: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Q_21443252.html

    var jsNC = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(nChilds));

    if (jsNC > 0) {
        var jsChildArr = ctypes.cast(xqChildArr, ostypes.TYPE.Window.array(jsNC).ptr).contents;

        for (var i = 0; i < jsNC; i++) {
            var wChild = jsChildArr[i];
            processWin(wChild);
        }

        ostypes.API('XFree')(xqChildArr);
    }
}

processWin(ostypes.HELPER.cachedDefaultRootWindow());
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is not right?

Comment: Thanks very much @n.m. for the reply. Its hard to explain, but by chance do you use Firefox? I created an addon that takes screenshot of all monitors then overlays that shot over all monitors in editor windows. then a "Window Wand" option, when user clicks it, then picks a window it selects the top most window which is behind the editor window i opened. I got it working on Windows and Mac, but with Linux there is just like a bunch of Windows between Ill create a text dump of the window detail Im seeing brb 15min. If you can do remote connect though I would really easily be able to show you.

Comment: Hey @n.m. I did a full screenshot, with data using above algo, and goal synopsis in the comment on the gist here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/28fa8f27c948119fa298#gistcomment-1546867 the data in the gist is the XQueryTree data using the above algo with anthing that is not `map_state` of `IsViewable` removed.

Comment: Oh wow @n.m. I also just did a "Manual look through data trying to identify windows" section in that comment and man I think the order is all right, its just that windows are broken up into like more then one element in that `XQueryData`

Comment: So this question is moot, my algorithm is correct, but after that manual analysis of that data I see my question should be "Understanding XQueryTree Data" I think Ill spend some more time researching it, but if you have any pointers that would be awesome, I'm so confused on why windows are broken up into multiple, i'm see weird patterns like each window has "a -1,-1 1x1 thing which closes that group" maybe, Im not sure just looking for patterns right now in that manual observation.