# Correlate groups from XQueryTree data to a window

Tags: linux, gtk, x11

I ran XQueryTree on all my windows and I got them in z-order from topmost at top of the array to bottom-most at bottom of array.

I then filtered out only what is visible by doing `XGetWindowAttributes` on each and removing it if it is not `map_state` of `IsVisible`

For each visible window, I check and get the `_NET_WM_PID`, `_NET_WM_NAME`, `x`, `y`, `height` (as `height + border_width`), and `width` (as `width + border_width`).

My data is at this gist and also at bottom: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/94562d08f243cd7ca7ec

My setup is of two monitors. And this is a fullscreenshot of them both:

[image]

There is one transparent window over each monitor, that is the height and width of the monitor, their titles are "nativeshot_canvas".

So looking through the data I see that windows are broken up into multiple entries by `XQueryTree`. My manual analysis tells me this:

1. "nativeshot_canvas" on left monitor
2. "nativeshot_canvas" on right monitor

   - UNKNOWN WINDOW 1
   - UNKNOWN WINDOW 2
3. horizontal menu bar on right monitor
4. horizontal menu bar on left monitor
5. vertical dock on right monitor
6. vertical dock on left monitor

   - UNKNOWN WINDOW 3
7. "Javascript Application" window
8. "Browser Console" window
9. "Mozilla Firefox" window with two tabs
10. "Desktop"

A graphic of the data and my manual analysis is below.

## THE QUESTION

Is there a way to programmatically identify which entries correlate to a single window? In my manual analysis I used some patterns I came up with in that each window group starts with either a `_NET_WM_PID` (`pid` key in data below) or a `_NET_WM_NAME` (`title` key in data below). I don't think this is a good pattern because we see at top things have a PID but their width and height are 1.

[image]

edit: still stuck on how finding a gurantteed way to correlate these divisions into groups of windows. i basically need to get all x, y, width, and height of all the windows out there, if anyone has any input i would be very greatful

### My code to list out the XQueryTree data:

```
            var xqRoot = ostypes.TYPE.Window();
            var xqParent = ostypes.TYPE.Window();
            var xqChildArr = ostypes.TYPE.Window.ptr();
            var nChilds = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_int();

            var gpTypeReturned = ostypes.TYPE.Atom();
            var gpFormatReturned = ostypes.TYPE.int();
            var gpNItemsReturned = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_long();
            var gpBytesAfterReturn = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_long();
            var gpItemsArr = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_char.ptr();

            var geoRoot = ostypes.TYPE.Window();
            var geoX = ostypes.TYPE.int();
            var geoY = ostypes.TYPE.int();
            var geoW = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_int();
            var geoH = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_int();
            var geoBorderWidth = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_int();
            var geoDepth = ostypes.TYPE.unsigned_int();

            var wAttr = ostypes.TYPE.XWindowAttributes();

            var processWin = function(w) {
                if (aOptions.filterVisible) {
                    var rez_WA = ostypes.API('XGetWindowAttributes')(ostypes.HELPER.cachedXOpenDisplay(), w, wAttr.address());
                    console.info('wAttr.map_state:', wAttr.map_state.toString());
                    if (!cutils.jscEqual(wAttr.map_state, ostypes.CONST.IsViewable)) {
                        return; // continue as this is a hidden window, do not list features, do not dig this window
                    }
                }

                var thisWin = {};
                // fetch props on thisWin

                thisWin.hwndXid = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(w));

                if (aOptions.getPid) {
                    var rez_pid = ostypes.API('XGetWindowProperty')(ostypes.HELPER.cachedXOpenDisplay(), w, ostypes.HELPER.cachedAtom('_NET_WM_PID'), 0, 1, ostypes.CONST.False, ostypes.CONST.XA_CARDINAL, gpTypeReturned.address(), gpFormatReturned.address(), gpNItemsReturned.address(), gpBytesAfterReturn.address(), gpItemsArr.address());
                    if (ostypes.HELPER.getWinProp_ReturnStatus(ostypes.CONST.XA_CARDINAL, gpTypeReturned, gpFormatReturned, gpBytesAfterReturn) == 1) {
                        var jsN = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(gpNItemsReturned));
                        if (jsN == 0) {
                            thisWin.pid = null; // set to null as this window did not have a pid, but i add the key indicating i tested for it and the window had the proerty
                        } else {
                            //console.info('gpItemsArr:', gpItemsArr.toString(), 'casted:', ctypes.cast(gpItemsArr, ostypes.TYPE.CARD32).toString(), 'casted to single el:', ctypes.cast(gpItemsArr, ostypes.TYPE.CARD32.array(1).ptr).contents.toString()); // "gpItemsArr:" "ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x7f229409d710"))" "casted:" "ctypes.unsigned_int(2483672848)" "casted to single el:" "ctypes.unsigned_int.array(1)([2212])" // showing that it must be cast and not just to type cuz its single element, but to array of 1 element
                            thisWin.pid = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(ctypes.cast(gpItemsArr, ostypes.TYPE.CARD32.array(1).ptr).contents[0]));
                        }
                        ostypes.API('XFree')(gpItemsArr);
                    } else {
                        thisWin.pid = undefined; // window didnt even have property
                    }
                }

                if (aOptions.getTitle) {
                    var rez_title = ostypes.API('XGetWindowProperty')(ostypes.HELPER.cachedXOpenDisplay(), w, ostypes.HELPER.cachedAtom('_NET_WM_NAME'), 0, 256 /* this number times 4 is maximum ctypes.char that can be returned*/, ostypes.CONST.False, ostypes.HELPER.cachedAtom('UTF8_STRING'), gpTypeReturned.address(), gpFormatReturned.address(), gpNItemsReturned.address(), gpBytesAfterReturn.address(), gpItemsArr.address());
                    if (ostypes.HELPER.getWinProp_ReturnStatus(ostypes.HELPER.cachedAtom('UTF8_STRING'), gpTypeReturned, gpFormatReturned, gpBytesAfterReturn) == 1) {
                        var jsN = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(gpNItemsReturned));
                        if (jsN == 0) {
                            thisWin.title = ''; // window had property but not title
                        } else {
                            thisWin.title = ctypes.cast(gpItemsArr, ostypes.TYPE.char.array(jsN).ptr).contents.readString();
                        }
                        ostypes.API('XFree')(gpItemsArr);
                    } else {
                        thisWin.title = undefined; // window didnt even have property
                    }
                }

                if (aOptions.getBounds) {
                    if (aOptions.filterVisible) {
                        // then get the info from wAttr as its already available
                        thisWin.left = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.x));
                        thisWin.top = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.y));

                        var borderWidth = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.border_width));
                        thisWin.borderWidth = borderWidth;

                        thisWin.width = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.width))/* + borderWidth*/;
                        thisWin.height = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.height))/* + borderWidth*/;

                        thisWin.right = thisWin.left + thisWin.width;
                        thisWin.bottom = thisWin.top + thisWin.height;
                    } else {
                        var rez_bounds = ostypes.API('XGetGeometry')(ostypes.HELPER.cachedXOpenDisplay(), w, geoRoot.address(), geoX.address(), geoY.address(), geoW.address(), geoH.address(), geoBorderWidth.address(), geoDepth.address());
                        thisWin.left = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(geoX));
                        thisWin.top = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(geoY));

                        var borderWidth = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.border_width));
                        thisWin.borderWidth = borderWidth;

                        thisWin.width = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.width))/* + borderWidth*/;
                        thisWin.height = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(wAttr.height))/* + borderWidth*/;

                        thisWin.right = thisWin.left + thisWin.width;
                        thisWin.bottom = thisWin.top + thisWin.height;
                    }
                }

                rezWinArr.splice(0, 0, thisWin);

                // dig the win even if it doesnt qualify
                var rez_XQ = ostypes.API('XQueryTree')(ostypes.HELPER.cachedXOpenDisplay(), w, xqRoot.address(), xqParent.address(), xqChildArr.address(), nChilds.address()); // interesting note about XQueryTree and workspaces: "The problem with this approach is that it will only return windows on the same virtual desktop.  In the case of multiple virtual desktops, windows on other virtual desktops will be ignored." source: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Q_21443252.html

                var jsNC = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(nChilds));

                if (jsNC > 0) {
                    var jsChildArr = ctypes.cast(xqChildArr, ostypes.TYPE.Window.array(jsNC).ptr).contents;

                    // for (var i=jsNC-1; i>-1; i--) {
                    for (var i=0; i<jsNC; i++) {
                        var wChild = jsChildArr[i];
                        processWin(wChild);
                    }

                    ostypes.API('XFree')(xqChildArr);
                }
            }

            processWin(ostypes.HELPER.cachedDefaultRootWindow());
```

Comment: "Is there a way to programmatically identify which entries correlate to a single window" - what do you mean? When you get response from QueryTree you already know window ids and parent/child relationship between ids. One id == one window

Comment: Thanks @AndreySidorov that's what I thought too but if we look at the data returned above, it seems one window == 2, 3, or 4 entries. We always see in the first entry by XQueryTree tha the left and top are wrong, and they are correct in the later entries.

Comment: I can't see window id's in your output - can you include them? One window can't have multiple parents, so I guess it's just the way you walk the tree ( you visit windows multiple times? Or include child and later again child when you visit it as subtree )

Comment: Thanks very much @Andrey for always helping out, the algo im using to walk the tree is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888887/proper-algorithm-for-xquerytree-to-get-in-z-order i hit each window then go to each child underneath, as i start at root and to get the children i go down deeper. What function would i use to get the id of the windows? edit: ooo i just realized how the id is the window im passing, ill get those right now

Comment: Aside: Using photoshop the actual geometry of the "Javascript Applicaiton" window is `425x138` and `446, 404` but these numbers are not seen in that "javascirpt applicaiton" group :(

Comment: Hey @AndreySidorov I still haven't been able to come up with a reliable algo to group these, do you have any ideas? :( I currently am doingalgo of grouping till i find next pid, but i dont think it is reliable.

Comment: can I look at your code? feel free to email it to andrey.sidorov at gmail

Comment: Thank you man so much!! I'll email you right away! :)

Comment: please post code here.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. and Andrey I added the code here.

Comment: Compare your output to `xwininfo -root -tree`.